# Imitate Passport authenticate behavior

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, handler

I'm using `passport.js` authentication for different API's and works fine, but I want to separate the code for each one and I'm stuck calling `passport.authenticate('facebook')`. I'll put Facebook code for example.

This works:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
const fb = require('fb');

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  clientSecret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  callbackURL: "https://127.0.0.1/facebook/authCallback/"
}, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
  return {accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb};
}));

// Entry point
app.get('/authorize/:clientId/:network', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('/:network/authCallback', (request, response) => {
  // Some code here...
});
```

But when I try to split it in a different file, it never *callback* from `passport.authenticate('facebook')`:

**sserve.js**:

```
const authUtils = require('./utils/authUtils');

app.get('/authorize/:clientId/:network', (request, response) => {
  authUtils.authorize(request.params.clientId, request.params.network);
});
```

**authUtils.js**:

```
async function authorize(clientId, network) {    
  try {
    config = await databaseUtils.getConfig(clientId, network);

    if(typeof(config) !== 'undefined') {
      passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: config.appId,
        clientSecret: config.appSecretKey,
        callbackURL: 'https://127.0.0.1/' + network + '/authCallback/'
      }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        return {accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb};
      }));

      // It reachs to this point but never comeback...
      passport.authenticate(network);
    } else {
      throw new Error(network + ' is not configured');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

After some debug test, the problem seems to be that `passport.authenticate(network)` doesn't make redirection to callback URL.

If I add:

```
app.get('/authorize/:clientId/:network', (request, response) => {
  authUtils.authorize(request.params.clientId, request.params.network);
  console.log(1);
  next();
});
```

Console shows "1" and browser return `404 Not Found`. Passport doesn't continue with the redirection process.

Answer (score 0):

The way that express knows that everything was fine in that step of the middleware is calling 'next' method, which is the third parameter  (request, response, next). 
So, try passing this third parameter to authorize method and call it after passport authentication:

**sserve.js:**

```
const authUtils = require('./utils/authUtils');

app.get('/authorize/:clientId/:network', (request, response, next) => {
  authUtils.authorize(request.params.clientId, request.params.network, response);
});
```

**authUtils.js:**

```
async function authorize(clientId, network, response) {    
  try {
    config = await databaseUtils.getConfig(clientId, network);

    if(typeof(config) !== 'undefined') {
      passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: config.appId,
        clientSecret: config.appSecretKey,
        callbackURL: 'https://127.0.0.1/' + network + '/authCallback/'
      }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        return {accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb};
      }));

      // It reachs to this point but never comeback...
      passport.authenticate(network);
      return response.send();
    } else {
      throw new Error(network + ' is not configured');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Comment: Now it returns a `404` for `/authorize/:clientId/:network`, not quiet sure why...

Comment: I think it's the `next`, because it reachs the `authUtils.authorize` function, and also ends `passport.authenticate(network)`.

Comment: As far as you don't have a next step, may be you can return a response, changing next() by   response.send();

Comment: It doesn't work, :(. The thing is that `passport.authenticate()` is a request handler, so I need to tell the request that, after doing the configuration, its handler is this function.

Comment: But you need to pass the response as param to authorize method, same as with next

Comment: Yes, I do. I think I was more clear in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945402/re-handle-request-after-changes

Comment: I meant here:
 authUtils.authorize(request.params.clientId, request.params.network, response);
I edited the code

Comment: Yep, I know what you mean, that's the reason I made the other question. I re-coded the `authorize` function to be a handler, receiving `request`, `response` and `next`. But I'm facing the same issue, I need to redirect the process to be handled by `passport.authenticate`.