# Re-handle request after changes

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, handler

I'm trying to use `passport.js` in a generic way, changing configuration before calling `authenticate`, but I can't find a way to redirect request to it after.

I handle request like this:

**Entry point**:

```
app.get('/authorize/:clientId/:network', authUtils.authorize);
```

**Handler**:

```
async function authorize(request, response, next) {
  try {
    let clientId = request.params.clientId;
    let network = request.params.network;

    config = await databaseUtils.getConfig(clientId, network);

    if(typeof(config) !== 'undefined') {
      passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: config.appId,
        clientSecret: config.appSecretKey,
        callbackURL: 'https://127.0.0.1/' + network + '/authCallback/'
      }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        return {accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb};
      }));

      // Here's where I should re-handle request
      passport.authenticate(network);
    } else {
      throw new Error(network + ' is not configured');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

I know for sure that using `passport.authenticate('network')` as request handler works, but I would like to make it generic so I can use different social networks.

Is there a way to "re-handle" a request in NodeJS/Express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all the steps of middleware should return a function with the 3 parameters, maybe you can call what it returns with these 3 parameters:

> return passport.authenticate(network)(request, response, next);

Comment: First option never ends the request. Second option... You sir, you are a genius! Thank you so much! I was fighting this for about a week now!

Comment: Great :). I'm going to addapt the answer for next with the same problem :)